# Сonversion failed when converting date and or/time from a character to string c# Помогите Решить

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, mysql-workbench

Никак не могу решить проблему с конверсией. В БД значение столбцов : date и time, использую DateTimePicker в WinForms и создаю новые переменные в которые записываю только дату и только время, передаю в запрос и ошибка Conversion failed .... 
Ошибка в строке string Query и SqlCommand comAdd = new SqlComman(Query, con);
Название ошибки в заголовке

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                    con.Open();

                string StartTime = HLStartTime.Value.Hour.ToString() + "-" + HLStartTime.Value.Minute.ToString() + "-" + HLStartTime.Value.Second.ToString();
                //string StartTime = HLStartTime.Value.ToString("hh-mm-ss");
                string FinishTime = HLFinishTime.Value.Hour.ToString() + "-" + HLFinishTime.Value.Minute.ToString() + "-" + HLFinishTime.Value.Second.ToString();
                //string FinishTime = HLFinishTime.Value.ToString("hh-mm-ss");
                string Date = DateOfOpening.Value.Year.ToString() + "-" + DateOfOpening.Value.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateOfOpening.Value.Day.ToString();
                //string Date = DateOfOpening.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                string Query = "INSERT INTO Hotlines (Name, Work_start_time, Work_end_time, Date_of_opening) VALUES('" + HotLineName.Text.ToString() + "', '" + StartTime + "', '" + FinishTime + "', '" + Date + "')";

                SqlCommand comAdd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
                comAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Hot line added");

                con.Close();
```

Comment: *передаю в запрос и ошибка Conversion failed ....* 1) Укажите точно, в какой строке ошибка - догадываться тупо лень; 2) Процитируйте точно сообщение об ошибке - сейчас даже не определить, кто именно её генерирует.

Comment: Выкиньте этот код и используйте параметризированные запросы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых абсолютно верно - используйте параметризированные запросы. А во вторых - какой тип у этих work_start_time,  work_end_time и т.д. в самой бд? если там тип datetime, timestamp, а вы пытаетесь ей пихать string, она и скажет ошибку конвертации.

---

У меня нет сейчас студии под рукой, но это всё должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    string sql = "INSERT INTO Hotlines (Name, Work_start_time, Work_end_time, Date_of_opening) VALUES(@Name, @Work_start_time, @Work_end_time, @Date_of_opening)";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", DbType.String).Value = HotLineName.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Work_start_time", DbType.Time).Value = HLStartTime.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Work_end_time", DbType.Time).Value = HLFinishTime.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_of_opening", DbType.Date).Value = DateOfOpening.Value;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Я указал что тип этих значений time и date, я делаю insert into запрос по этому конвертирую в string . Не совсем понимаю что такое  параметризированные запросы

Comment: Обновил ответ. Вот это и есть параметризированные запросы. Она же и пишет - у вас ошибка конвертации. Не может получить дату из вашего string. 
p.s. И я бы просто использовал везде полный Datetime, а из него вы брал что и когда нужно (время, дату)

Comment: В целом верно. Ну и по традиции: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Ваш вариант мне понравился но проблему решил по другому, там где я делал конвертацию времени string StartTime и FinishTime разделителями должны быть " : " а не " - "  изменил и все работает

Comment: Так как у вас - делать в любом случае нельзя по целой куче причин, первая же из которых - безопасность.